Error NU1605: Package downgrade when updating Azure.Identity in SDK-style .NET Framework project using Central Package Management
I’ve migrated some legacy .NET Framework projects to SDK-style projects and switched to using Central Package Management. When I try to update the Azure.Identity package to version 1.12.0, I get the following error in Visual Studio:
Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal from 4.61.3 to 4.57.0.
Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 

APIFunctionalTests -> Azure.Identity 1.12.0 -> Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal (>= 4.61.3) 
APIFunctionalTests -> Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal (>= 4.57.0)

I understand that Azure.Identity requires Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal (>= 4.61.3), but my project seems to be referencing version 4.57.0. Since I’m using Central Package Management, there are no csproj files to manually edit. I was under the impression that installing Azure.Identity 1.12.0 should automatically update Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal to version 4.61.3 in my Directory.Packages.props file, but this is not happening.
Here are the steps I’ve tried so far:

Directly referencing Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal in the
central package file (Directory.Packages.props) with version 4.57.0.

What else can I do to resolve this package downgrade error?
